# Can't use a variable in another method in XNA

Tags: for-loop, xna

I will explain in depth after. So here is my code, we have an Elevation[] variable and each Elevation gets a random number:

```
public void elevation()
    {
        for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (y = (int)Width - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                y = rand.Next((int)MaxElevation); //random number for each y.
                Elevation[x] = y; //each Elevation gets a random number.
            }
        }
    }
```

After this I try to use this random number in the draw method like this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Pixel, new Rectangle((int)Position.X + x, (int)Position.Y - Elevation[x], 1, (int)Height), Color.White);
            //HERE, I try to acces the random number for each Elevation (y value). But I get 0 everywhere.
        }
    }
```

How can I acces this random number?

If I do that:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (y = (int)Width - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                y = rand.Next((int)MaxElevation);
                spriteBatch.Draw(Pixel, new Rectangle((int)Position.X + x, (int)Position.Y - Elevation[y], 1, (int)Height), Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

I will be able to acces the random numbers, but it will update every frame and the random numbers will change. So I need to calculate them once and then use them.

Here is all the code:

```
namespace procedural_2dterrain
{
  class Terrain
{
    Texture2D Pixel;
    Vector2 Position;
    Random rand;

    int[] Elevation;

    float MaxElevation;
    float MinElevation;

    float Width;
    float Height;

    int x;
    int y;


    public void Initialize( ContentManager Content, float maxElevation, float minElevation, float width, float height, Vector2 position)
    {
        Pixel = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pixel");
        rand = new Random();

        Elevation = new int[(int)width];

        MaxElevation = maxElevation;
        MinElevation = minElevation;

        Width = width;
        Height = height;

        Position = position;

        elevation();

    }

    public void Update()
    {
    }

    public void elevation()
    {
        for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (y = (int)Width - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                y = rand.Next((int)MaxElevation);
                Elevation[x] = y;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Pixel, new Rectangle((int)Position.X + x, (int)Position.Y - Elevation[x], 1, (int)Height), Color.White);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show your declaration of elevation. Where is it declared?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `elevation()` method. You are using `y` as your inner loop indexer and also assigning a value to it within the loop. So the loop starts, y is assigned a random value. As it continues the loop, it is decremented and then tested for being `>=0`. The only time this loop will exit is if `y` is assigned the random number of `0`. So that is why all your `Elevation` are zero.

I am a little confused as to why you think you need an inner loop. Try:

```
public void elevation()
{
    for (x = (int)Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {            
        Elevation[x] = rand.Next((int)MaxElevation);            
    }
}
```